# Picking balls from urns, probability problem

Tags: probability

An urn contains one black ball and one white ball. At every time step, a ball is chosen randomly from the urn and returned with another new ball of the same color. (So at time $ t $ there are a total of $ t+2 $ balls). What is the probability that at time $ t $ there are $ b $ black balls?

I thought about it for a while and can't really see how to start, So I'll be glad if someone can share an idea. My knowledge in probability is very low right now (I'm learning the basics), what I can use to solve this problem is Bayes' rule, conditional probability and the basic definitions of probability space and probability measures.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @lulu done, sorry

Comment: Hint for your question:  work out the first few cases.  At time $t=2$ there are three possible states, namely $(3,1),(2,2), (1,3)$.  What is the probability of landing in each state?  What about $t=3$?  A pattern should start to emerge.

Comment: @lulu I tried actually up to t=4n cant see a pattern.

Comment: Then you did it wrong.  What's the answer for $t=2$?  What's the answer for $t=3$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Denote a state by the ordered pair $(b,w)$ where $b$ is the number of black balls, and $w$ the number of white.

The, somewhat unintuitive, fact is that all states at a given time are equi-probable.  As there $t+1$ possible states at time $t$, the probability of each must therefore be $\frac 1{t+1}$.

To see this, we proceed inductively.  The claim is easily verified for small $t$, suppose it holds up to $t-1$.

Consider time $t$.  Clearly the extreme state $(t+1,1)$ can only be reached by drawing black each time.  The probability of that is $$\frac 12\times \frac 23\times \frac 34\times \cdots \times \frac {t-1}{t}\times \frac t{t+1}=\frac 1{t+1}$$ and similarly for the state $(1, t+1)$.

All the other states can be reached from two different states in time $t-1$.  Specifically, the state $(b, t+2-b)$ can be reached from $(b-1, t+2-b)$ by choosing black or from $(b, t+1-b)$ by choosing white.  By the induction hypothesis, both of the states at time $t-1$ have probability $\frac 1t$, so the probability of reaching $(b-1, t+2-b)$ is $$\frac 1t\times \left(\frac {b-1}{t+1}+\frac {t+1-b}{t+1}\right)=\frac 1{t+1}$$ and we are done.

Comment: That was a very clear explanation, thank you.

Comment: @lulu: I often appreciate your creative and instructive solutions with respect to probability problems. Maybe you find *[this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3848268)* interesting. Best regards,

Comment: @MarkusScheuer  Thank!  I've posted something on that problem...nothing very elegant, but a different approach than the other posted solutions (I believe).

Answer (score 0):

At first there are $2$ balls to pick, then there are $3$, then $4$, so on until there are $t+1$. There are $(t+1)!$ possibilities.

At first, there are $1$ black ball to pick, then there are $2$, then $3$, so on until there are $b-1$. There are $(b-1)!$ possibilities.

At first, there are $1$ white ball to pick, then there are $2$, then $3$, so on until there are $t+1-b$. There are $(t+1-b)!$ possibilities.

From $t$ times picking, which picks result in black ball? $\binom{t}{b-1}$

$$
\frac{\binom{t}{b-1}(b-1)!(t+1-b)!}{(t+1)!}=\frac{1}{t+1}
$$

Comment: I do not really ubderstand your solution. Can you elaborate?  Each paragraph ends up with " there are x possibilities" well, x possibilities for what? This is unclear. Also its not clear why are we multiplying by  t choose b-1